# How can I secure Spring controller to not accept wrong type of path variables passes in URL?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url, controller, path-variables

I have following controller in my Spring app:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    // Display single user details
    @RequestMapping(path = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUser(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
        if(userService.getUser(id) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUser(id));
            return "user_details";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/users";
        }
    }
```

It works as I want: if user exists in the DB, then it's details are being displayed. If not, I am being redirected to list of all users.
**But**, it works well only when I specify Integer ID. It is causing an error when I provide other type of argument.
For example: `http://localhost:8080/users/a` gives following error message:

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
```

It is obvious, since it expects an Integer. **My question here is:**
Should I secure my Controller method somehow (if yes, how can it be done) to handle wrong parameter type OR it is a bad practice to use an Integer for path variables and I should refactor my code to use String instead? What is the best practice?

Comment: Something like `/users/{id:\\d+}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using `/users/{id:\\d+}`

So my Controller looks like below now:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    // Display single user details
    @RequestMapping(path = "/users/{id:\\d+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUser(Model model, @PathVariable(value = "id") Integer id) {
        if(userService.getUser(id) != null) {
            model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUser(id));
            return "user_details";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/users";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your user class to use UUID - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

if you are using hibernate

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
@Column(name = "uuid", unique = true)
private String uuid;
```

Or you can just generate :

```
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: That will not work in my case - I need to have numeric IDs

Comment: It is just proposal for refactoring. I love to use UUID and use it everywhere I can.

Comment: Need parse uuid from request param or thrown a exception like as integer.